# Make the difference between the outbound flight and the return flight using Amadeus Flight Offer API

Tags: amadeus

I'm using the flight offers API with PHP to get some flight offers with stopovers

This is what i get for the first flight offer

```
                "duration": "PT16H",
                "segments": [
                    {
                        "departure": {
                            "iataCode": "SYD",
                            "terminal": "1",
                            "at": "2021-11-04T22:15:00"
                        },
                        "arrival": {
                            "iataCode": "KUL",
                            "terminal": "M",
                            "at": "2021-11-05T03:50:00"
                        },
                        "carrierCode": "MH",
                        "number": "140",
                        "aircraft": {
                            "code": "333"
                        },
                        "operating": {
                            "carrierCode": "MH"
                        },
                        "duration": "PT8H35M",
                        "id": "1",
                        "numberOfStops": 0,
                        "blacklistedInEU": false
                    },
                    {
                        "departure": {
                            "iataCode": "KUL",
                            "terminal": "M",
                            "at": "2021-11-05T09:00:00"
                        },
                        "arrival": {
                            "iataCode": "BKK",
                            "at": "2021-11-05T10:15:00"
                        },
                        "carrierCode": "MH",
                        "number": "784",
                        "aircraft": {
                            "code": "738"
                        },
                        "operating": {
                            "carrierCode": "MH"
                        },
                        "duration": "PT2H15M",
                        "id": "2",
                        "numberOfStops": 0,
                        "blacklistedInEU": false
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "duration": "PT20H25M",
                "segments": [
                    {
                        "departure": {
                            "iataCode": "BKK",
                            "at": "2021-11-10T20:05:00"
                        },
                        "arrival": {
                            "iataCode": "KUL",
                            "terminal": "M",
                            "at": "2021-11-10T23:20:00"
                        },
                        "carrierCode": "MH",
                        "number": "781",
                        "aircraft": {
                            "code": "738"
                        },
                        "operating": {
                            "carrierCode": "MH"
                        },
                        "duration": "PT2H15M",
                        "id": "5",
                        "numberOfStops": 0,
                        "blacklistedInEU": false
                    },
                    {
                        "departure": {
                            "iataCode": "KUL",
                            "terminal": "M",
                            "at": "2021-11-11T09:10:00"
                        },
                        "arrival": {
                            "iataCode": "SYD",
                            "terminal": "1",
                            "at": "2021-11-11T20:30:00"
                        },
                        "carrierCode": "MH",
                        "number": "141",
                        "aircraft": {
                            "code": "333"
                        },
                        "operating": {
                            "carrierCode": "MH"
                        },
                        "duration": "PT8H20M",
                        "id": "6",
                        "numberOfStops": 0,
                        "blacklistedInEU": false
                    }
                ]
            }
```

As you can see,

- the outbound flight is from SYD to KUL and then from KUL to BKK
- the return flight is from BKK to KUL and then from KUL to SYD

My question is : does the API have a tag to differentiate between the outbound and the return flight ?

I want to loop through the body result and return only the outbound flight and display it on my page.

This is what i've done so far but it just prints everything

```
 $response_body = callAmadeusAPI($endpoint,$travel_data,$access_token);
        //echo '<pre>', json_encode($response_body->data, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT), '</pre>';
        //echo $response_body['data'];
        foreach($response_body->data as $data)
        {
            foreach($data->itineraries as $itineraries)
            {
                foreach($itineraries->segments as $segments )
                {
                    //echo '<br>'.$itineraries->duration.'</br>';
                    var_dump($segments);
                }
                
            }
            //var_dump($data->itineraries);
        }
```

Can you help me ?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

bounds: Bound[]

Each bound corresponds to a group of flights. A one way trip contains one single bound. A round trip or open jaw trip contains two bounds (outbound and inbound)